# Can't connect to MySQL with hostname wildcard

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

I installed `MySQL` to my Mac (with MAMP installer) and have a problem. When I create a user with "@%" hostname this way:

```
CREATE USER 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
```

and I try to connect via CLI: `mysql -u test -ptest`, I get this error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

But when I change hostname to localhost:

`RENAME USER 'test'@'%' TO 'test'@'localhost';`

it works.

Any idea how to make MySQL use the wildcard?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw/. Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw/11216911#11216911

Answer (score 0):

As YaK suggests, it is because of anonymous user `''@'localhost'` created by MySQL installation. Problem was solved after removal of this user. Thanks a lot YaK!